# Show most up to date index.html when visiting site

Tags: html

I have a website and if you go to `www.domainname.com/sitename/` it always shows an old cached file, but if you go to `www.domainname.com/sitename/index.html` it shows the most up to date. Is there a way of ensuring the user sees the most up to date without typing **index.html**?

Comment: You can reload the page without using caches. This may help: https://superuser.com/a/89811

Comment: If you are in Chrome try to load the page in an incognito windows and reload with ctrl + shift + R. Also check if your site use some plugin or component for cache or something

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what hoster/server you are using, but usually caching can be controlled by putting a file called ".htaccess" in the base folder, containing something like

```
Header set Expires 0
FileETag None
```

Or similar...

You should check your hoster's documentation first, otherwise try what you can find by googling.

Also, please note that caching is a good thing and it's better to configure it correctly than just disabling it. However if you don't expect much traffic, then it probably does not matter.